# Accessing Android 6.0 all audio out buffer for streaming over WiFi-Direct

Tags: android, audio, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifi-direct

I'm a newbie to programming on Android (who got sent here by Android.SE) and I was wondering if the following is possible:

Can i access the audio out buffer that would play on the system speaker? If yes, what would be the best way to go about accessing it.

I'm trying to make an android app that will send said audio buffer over WiFi-Direct to a Raspberry Pi 3, but I have no idea how to find this one specific buffer on android 6.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching for a solution, it seems quite clear that there is no legal way to do this for privacy reasons.